# GWTTestCase was not found in the classpath

Tags: java, gwt, junit

Iam using eclipse juno and gwt 2.5, i follow the [gwt Junit test tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JUnit)
when i create the Test-class which extends by GWTTestCase i get this message:

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for junit.framework.TestCase. Fix the build path then try building this project    homeopathischeAnwendung     Unknown Java Problem`

what to do?

Comment: Are using ant or maven? Are you using just eclipse?

Comment: iam using just Eclipse without maven or Ant.

Answer (score 1):

Junit is missing from your classpath : http://junit.sourceforge.net/

or the maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
There was a mistake which i made at the beginning.

I downloaded the junit.jar and added it to the buildpath.
That was false.
The right way to add junit with eclipse by right-clicking in the package explorer on the gwt.project ->  Build Path -> Add Library -> JUnit.

The second mistake i made was the location where my Test-Class was.
I created an extra folder named "Test" and in this folder i put the package with the Test-Class.
that was false too.

```
MyGwtApplication
src
    package.number.one
        MyGwtApplication.gwt.xml
    package.number.one.client
        MyGwtApplication.java
test
    package.number.one.testing
        MyTestClass.java
```

Thats false!

The test-class must be in the src folder

```
MyGwtApplication
src
    package.number.one
        MyGwtApplication.gwt.xml
    package.number.one.client
        MyGwtApplication.java
    package.number.one.client.testing
        MyTestClass.java
```

Comment: You should move to maven or ant for "build" if it is non-academic project. Also Note - GWT provides sample for both ant and maven set up in its sample projects.